# atop - how to check what process locked folder during umount?

Tags: mount, process, lock, atop

I have some software which unmounting folder during it's operation. But for some reason it can't do it. When I trying to umount folder manually (almost in same time) it does work. Can someone let me know if atop utility can track process usage for some folder? As I can't see any process using exact file with lsof/fuser/ps.

Comment: I do not know if atop can do such a thing but, probably, you missed `-m` option of `fuser`. Try `fuser -m MOUNTPOINT`.

Comment: no, I used fuser -vm. No data.